# Difference between spring httpsession and tomcat session

Tags: java, spring, tomcat, servlets

Is there any difference/correlation between spring httpsession and Tomcat session?

I have read Tomcat documentation but still I don't understand how it is related to deployed web apps.

Comment: Are you talking about Spring Session ?

Comment: @GovindParashar yes

Comment: @itpr Are you sure? Do you know that Spring Session is an additional  framework. It is not included in Spring. What frameworks do you use?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No , they refer to the same things. You can think that Tomcat is responsible for creating and managing the actual session instance.

When a web app deployed on Tomcat need to access the session , it will ask Tomcat to give it by `HttpServletRequest#getSession()`.